# Apollo: Refetch queries that have multiple variable permutations after mutation

Tags: apollo

Let's say I have a table that lists a bunch of Posts using a query like:

```
const PostsQuery = gql`
  query posts($name: string) {
    posts {
      id
      name
      status
    }
  }
`;

const query = apolloClient.watchQuery({query: PostsQuery});
query.subscribe({
  next: (posts) => console.log(posts) // [ {name: "Post 1", id: '1', status: 'pending' }, { name: "Paul's Post", id: '2', status: 'pending'} ]
});
```

Then later my user comes along and enters a value in a search field and calls this code:

```
query.setVariables({name: 'Paul'})
```

It fetches the filtered posts and logs it out fine.

```
// [ { name: "Paul's Post", id: '2', status: 'pending'} ]
```

Now, in my table there is a button that changes the status of a post from 'Pending' to 'Active'. The user clicks that and it calls code like:

```
const PostsMutation = gql`
   mutation activatePost($id: ID!) {
     activatePost(id: $id) {
        ok
        object {
           id
           name
           status
        }
     }
   }
`;
apolloClient.mutate({mutation: PostsMutation});
```

All is well with the mutation, but now I want to refetch the table data so it has the latest, so I make a change:

```
apolloClient.mutate({
  mutation: PostsMutation,
  refetchQueries: [{query: PostsQuery, variables: {name: 'Paul'}]
});
```

Hurray, it works!

```
// [ { name: "Paul's Post", id: '2', status: 'active'} ]
```

But... now my user clears the search query, expecting the results to update.

```
query.setVariables({});

// [ {name: "Post 1", id: '1', status: 'pending' }, { name: "Paul's Post", id: '2', status: 'pending'} ]
```

Oh no! Because the data was not refetched in our mutation with our "original" variables (meaning none), we are getting stale data!

So how do you handle a situation where you have a mutation that may affect a query that could have many permutations of variables?

Comment: There are 2 potential reasons why you did not get an answer yet: Your question is too long and your use of the word permutation.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, I am using Apollo with Angular, so I am not sure if this method will work with React Client, but it should.

If you look closely at `refetchQueries` properties on the `mutate` method, you will see that the function can also return a string array of query names to refetch. By returning just the query name as a string, you do not need to worry about the variables. Be advised that this will refetch all the queries matching the name. So if you had a lot queries with different variables it could end up being a large request.  But, in my case it is worth the trade off. If this is a problem, you could also get access to the `queryManager` through `apolloClient.queryManager` which you could use to do some more fine grained control of what to refetch. I didn't implement it, but it looked very possible. I found the solution below fits my needs fine.

In your code, what you need to do is:

```
apolloClient.mutate({
 mutation: PostsMutation,
 refetchQueries: (mutationResult) => ['PostQueries']
});
```

This will refetch any query with the name 'PostQueries'. Again, it is possible to only refetch a subset of them if you dig into the queryManager and do some filtering on the active watch queries. But, that is another exercise.